# zurb foundation with single responsive image in row for 320 - 480 screen size

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I just started to explorer zurb foundation and i am wondering how to show one image in a row if device screen size is between 320 - 480 px.

Example http://jsfiddle.net/8ww2v/

Desktop Version
Row one: slider
Row two: 4 images
Row three: 3 images

Row Two & Three can be of any of following matrix 4x6, 4x4, 4x3 and 3x6, 3x4, 3x3 also

Mobile Version
With the current code it breaks the row formation of two image in row and show two images even for a small screen 320px width.

`image image`

`image image`

`image image`

What i want is that if screen width is between 320 - 480 then it should show 1 image in a row

`image`

`image`

`image`

`image`

`image`

`image`

`image`

I am not sure how to achieve this in foundation or what properties i need to change i tried few things but it did not work

I want some think like this to happen for screen 320 - 480
[image]

```
   <div class="row">
          <p>
    <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">   
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&text=%5Bimg%5D"/>
      <p>Lorem sorum Lorem sorum  Lorem sorum  Lorem sorum </p>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&text=%5Bimg%5D"/>
      <p>Lorem sorum Lorem sorum  Lorem sorum  Lorem sorum </p>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 small-6 columns">  
       <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400&text=%5Bimg%5D"/>
      <p>Lorem sorum Lorem sorum  Lorem sorum  Lorem sorum </p>
    </div>
          </p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ww2v/3/)

```
@media all and (max-width: 320px){
 .columns {
    float:none !important;
 }
 .small-6{
    width:100%;

     }
}
```

Comment: But it is not stretching the image as show in the example image that is how i want it to showup

Comment: Give max-width:100%; for columns class